# How to split screen in two colors bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have an angular component and needs to split screen in two colors using bootstrap 4... but i have this:
[image]

the problem is that on the right side, the black box does not occupy all the space ... there is a white space, ie the black space does not occupy all the space that should occupy..

home.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-6 background">
      <p class="p-style">text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-6 background2">
      <p class="p-style">text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

home.css:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}

.background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(0, 121, 175);
    background-size: cover;
    color: rgb(67, 67, 67);
    text-align: center;
 }

 .background2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    color: rgb(67, 67, 67);
    text-align: center;
 }
 .p-style{
    font-size: 20px;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin:auto;
 }
```

My question is how can I split the screen in two symmetrically using bootstrap?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `container` class has a max-width specified. So, if you unset that, it works fine.

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    max-width: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way without relying on bootstrap, since you are using flex

```css
.container {
  display: flex;    
  height: 100vh;  
  background-color: red;
}

.container .col {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.container .col:nth-child(2)
{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>  
</div>
```